# String conversion to a mathematical expression

Tags: c++, tree, postfix-notation

I've written an application that converts a string into a mathematical expression for evaluation. This is done by converting the string into `postfix` and then by constructing an expression tree and solving it.

Now I want to know though, what is the most efficient way to do conversion into postfix?

Sample expression -

> (2+(3*4+(4/(3*(4+6))))) or (3+4) or 3+4

Comment: Your string already is a mathematical expression. You haven't told us how you did, it so your question about efficiency is unanswerable.

Comment: This is the form in which the user will enter the string , now what I have to do is to convert it into a mathematical expression to be solved.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the most efficient way". There are only methods that have a chance to be more efficient than other methods for a specific class of tasks in a specific  class of environments. You should not care about any of this unless your program is demonstrably too slow.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you consult [Sedgewick's Algorithms, 4th ed](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/). The code from the book for converting arithmetic expressions into postfix form is available [from the website](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this question is about the algorithm, BUT - If I would have to something like that I would use something like [BOOST::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/) to just exec the string as python code and get the result. I like to avoid writing code, If I can..